# Cannot open source file SFML/Graphics.hpp when including a header from a different project

Tags: c++, lua, sfml, premake

The project all together is a game engine. However, for this aspect I am trying to add a development tool that uses SFML to display a graph. I have successfully linked SFML to get it working on its own. The problem occurs when I try to #include the header from the tool into another project within the solution. I get an error saying the graphics.hpp in the SFML library cannot be found.
I am using a premake5.lua file to statically link SFML.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the segment of code for the premake. The .bat file can't build if I try to include the SFML into the sandbox project.

```
project "Sandbox"
location "sandbox"
kind "ConsoleApp"
language "C++"
staticruntime "off"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("build/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files {
    "%{prj.name}/include/**.h",
    "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp",
    "vendor/stb_image/stb_image.cpp"
}

includedirs {
    "%{prj.name}/include",
    "engine/enginecode/",
    "engine/enginecode/include/independent",
    "engine/precompiled/",
    "vendor/glm/",
    "vendor/spdlog/include",
    "vendor/json/single_include/nlohmann",
    "vendor/IMAT3904/include",
    "vendor/IMAT3904/include/include/independent",
    "vendor/React3D/src"
    "vendor/SFML-2.5.1/lib"
}

links {
    "Engine",
    "React3D",
}

filter "system:windows"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    systemversion "latest"

    defines {
        "NG_PLATFORM_WINDOWS"
    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines {
        "NG_DEBUG"
        "SFML_STATIC"
    }
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "On"

    libdirs {
        "vendor/SFML-2.5.1/lib"
    }

    links {
        "sfml-main",
        "sfml-graphics-s-d",
        "sfml-system-s-d",
        "sfml-window-s-d",
        "sfml-audio-s-d",
        "opengl32.lib",
        "winmm.lib",
        "gdi32.lib",
        "openal32.lib",
        "flac.lib",
        "vorbisenc.lib",
        "vorbisfile.lib",
        "vorbis.lib",
        "ogg.lib",
        "freetype.lib"
    }

    debugenvs {"PATH=$PATH;../vendor/SFML-2.5.1/bin;"}

filter "configurations:Release"
    defines {
        "NG_RELEASE"
        "SFML_STATIC"
    }
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "On"

    libdirs {
        "vendor/SFML-2.5.1/lib"
    }

    links {
        "sfml-main",
        "sfml-graphics-s",
        "sfml-system-s",
        "sfml-window-s",
        "sfml-audio-s",
        "opengl32.lib",
        "winmm.lib",
        "gdi32.lib",
        "openal32.lib",
        "flac.lib",
        "vorbisenc.lib",
        "vorbisfile.lib",
        "vorbis.lib",
        "ogg.lib",
        "freetype.lib"
    }

    debugenvs {"PATH=$PATH;../vendor/SFML-2.5.1/bin;"}
```

project "ProfilingTool"
    location "ProfilingTool"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "off"

```
targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("build/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files {
        "%{prj.name}/include/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
}

includedirs {
    "%{prj.name}/include",
    "vendor/spdlog/include",
    "vendor/stb_image",
    "vendor/freetype2/include",
    "vendor/glm/",
    "vendor/assimp/include",
    "vendor/Glad/include",
    "vendor/glfw/include",
    "vendor/json/single_include/nlohmann",
    "vendor/IMAT3904/include",
    "vendor/SFML-2.5.1/include"
}   

filter "system:windows"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    systemversion "latest"

filter "configurations:Debug"
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "On"
    defines "SFML_STATIC"

    libdirs {
        "vendor/SFML-2.5.1/lib"
    }

    links {
        "sfml-main",
        "sfml-graphics-s-d",
        "sfml-system-s-d",
        "sfml-window-s-d",
        "sfml-audio-s-d",
        "opengl32.lib",
        "winmm.lib",
        "gdi32.lib",
        "openal32.lib",
        "flac.lib",
        "vorbisenc.lib",
        "vorbisfile.lib",
        "vorbis.lib",
        "ogg.lib",
        "freetype.lib"
    }   

    debugenvs {"PATH=$PATH;../vendor/SFML-2.5.1/bin;"}

filter "configurations:Release"
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "On"
    defines "SFML_STATIC"

    libdirs {
        "vendor/SFML-2.5.1/lib"
    }

    links {
        "sfml-main",
        "sfml-graphics-s",
        "sfml-system-s",
        "sfml-window-s",
        "sfml-audio-s",
        "opengl32.lib",
        "winmm.lib",
        "gdi32.lib",
        "openal32.lib",
        "flac.lib",
        "vorbisenc.lib",
        "vorbisfile.lib",
        "vorbis.lib",
        "ogg.lib",
        "freetype.lib"
    }

    debugenvs {"PATH=$PATH;../vendor/SFML-2.5.1/bin;"}
```

It does include SFML for the profiling tool but not for the sandbox project.

Comment: Please add some code segments, the actual error messages you receive and your project structure. It will allow the SO community to understand your problem and help you with the solution.

Comment: If you are under windows ensure that you have specified the include to the compiler the folder for header files of SFML (location where you can find SFML/Graphics.hpp)